# Restore item from recycle bin to Document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, recycle-bin

How do i recover a file from a recycle bin to a document library that has been deleted?
Note : The original document library of the item has been deleted. The file is present in the recycle bin.

While trying to recycle the file, it is unable to find the location to restore it.
Even creating a new library with the same name doesn't work .

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks,
Aravind.

Comment: Isn't the original document library also in Recycle bin? You will need to restore that first followed by the deleted file.

Comment: The original library has been deleted from the recycle bin . Is there a way to do it now  ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Recycle Bin. Select the item and then click on Restore selection.

**UPDATE**
If the original library is also deleted and is present in the site collection recycle bin, then restore that first. However, if it is not present in the site collection recycle bin; then I am afraid there is no way of getting it back.

Comment: I have edited the question .

Comment: Thanks Nadeem. I think the only way is now to get a previous backup of the site and restore the library back to its place.